# Is there a way to add multiple conditions in a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
    n=int(raw_input('enter the number of mcnuggets you want to buy : ')) #total number of               mcnuggets you want yo buy
    for a in range(1,n) and b in range(1,n) and c in range(1,n) :
        if (6*a+9*b+20*c==n):
            print 'number of packs of 6 are ',a
            print 'number of packs of 9 are ',b
            print 'number of packs of 20 are',c
```

i am new to programming and i am learning python.the code above gives errors. Any suggestion.?.

Comment: the error is that it gives that variable b is not defined .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: "the code above gives errors"?  Really?  What errors?  Please **update** the question to include the errors with the code.  Please do not comment on your own question.   Please update it.

Comment: `a in range(1,n) and b in range(1,n) and c in range(1,n)` is not "multiple conditions".  It's not clear what you mean but this, but it can't be called multiple conditions.  Can you **update** the question to explain what you think you're trying to do.

Comment: the answer by yossi is exactly what i was trying to do. nested loops. sorry for providing wrong info i am new to programming. Also please tell me how to exactly update your question. I cant find any such option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use nested loops:

```
for a in range(1, n):
    for b in range(1, n):
        for c in range(1, n):
            if ...
```

Or even better:

```
import itertools

for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(1, n + 1), repeat=3):
    if ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you should start the ranges from 0, otherwise you will only get answers that include at least one of each size. You can also make less work for the computer since you know that there will never be more than `n/6` packs of 6 required etc. This can be a big saving - for 45 nuggets you only need to test 144 cases compared to 97336

```
from itertools import product
n=int(raw_input('enter the number of mcnuggets you want to buy : ')) #total number of mcnuggets you want to buy
for a,b,c in product(range(n//6+1), range(n//9+1), range(n//20+1)) :
    if (6*a+9*b+20*c==n):
        print 'number of packs of 6 are ',a
        print 'number of packs of 9 are ',b
        print 'number of packs of 20 are',c
```

itertools.product gives the [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the 3 ranges. For example

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product(range(3),range(4),range(5)))
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 4), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 4), (0, 2, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 2, 2), (0, 2, 3), (0, 2, 4), (0, 3, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 3, 2), (0, 3, 3), (0, 3, 4), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 0, 3), (1, 0, 4), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 0), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 0), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (2, 0, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 0, 2), (2, 0, 3), (2, 0, 4), (2, 1, 0), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 0), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 0), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: -1: Good answer.  But, not  appropriate for beginners struggling with their homework.

Comment: yeah actually about the range i figured that out before you answered and thanks for the itertools info-its seems like a promising tool.

Comment: @Danny, yes it does. `range()` does have unusual rules regarding it's optional parameters. n/6 becomes a floating point in Python3, n//6 is always an int and works ok in Python2 too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have values from multiple sequences in a `for` loop then you can use `zip`, for example:

```
for (a,b,c) in zip(xrange(1,n), xrange(1,n), xrange(1,n)) :
    ....
```

Of course it is a waste repeating the same range, but judging from the title of your post I guess that using the same range is only and example.