# two variable in for loop in python

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, for-loop

My question is about for loops in python. When I use C, I use two variables in the same for loop like this:

```
for (i=0, j=5; i<5, j>0; i++, j--)
```

How can I create this for loop in python?

Comment: Check out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774980/is-there-a-way-to-add-multiple-conditions-in-a-for-loop?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add multiple conditions in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774980/is-there-a-way-to-add-multiple-conditions-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: I hope you realise that `i<5, j>0` is effectively just `j>0`.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis and Sruthi V: That's not a duplicate. That question is about trying all possibilities for all variables, which is not what this C code does.

Comment: Why -2?! I think it is useful question.

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev probably because the example C code is bad?   Using compound expessions, comma operators etc. in flow-of-control statements is just asking for trouble - confusion, testing and debugging problems and maintenance/enhancement engineers cursing the keyboard it was typed on:(

Comment: @MartinJames, YOUR???

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev OOPS!!!!   Sorry - my bad. Bad Martin, [slap]   I go to doghouse, tail between legs:(

Comment: @MartinJames, heh. NP

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to iterate over two ranges in parallel:

```
for i,j in zip(range(0,5), range(5,0,-1)):
    print(i,j)

0 5
1 4
2 3
3 2
4 1
```